# What command is Thunar using to mount USB device?

Tags: mount, thunar

I set up `rsync` as an hourly `cron` job to back up data to an external USB device which is always plugged into my machine.

I see that Thunar (version 1.6.3 / Xubuntu 13.10) can mount this device when I just click on it in the left pane of the file manager under Devices. I can also right-click to "eject" it.

I want to know the actual command Thunar uses to mount/unmount the device without needing `sudo`. Then I can put the same command in autostart so that `rsync` can do its work. Now, if I forget to mount the USB device, `rsync` won't do the backup.

Comment: I'm not sure how Thunar does it, but I'm not sure of a way of mounting/unmounting filesystems other than `mount` and `umount`

Comment: You could turn on automounting whenever a USB device is connected to the computer.

Answer (score 6):

Thunar, in xubuntu, uses udisks for it's volume management. Having said so, once thunar-volman is notified about a new device from udev, it does:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/$block
```

It just replaces block with whatever is being mounted, and throws it in /media, depending on the label in the filesystem. Some file managers use a dbus call to org.freedesktop to access the udisk mount methods, but whether it's the dbus call or the udisksctrl command, as long as there is a rule in your policy kit config, the command will run.

Ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204350&page=2&p=12925064#post12925064

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Thunar uses the udisks2 daemon in the background.

Which is a useful information - in my case, it helped me to add big_writes and lazytime to the default mount options for NTFS volumes (catered for by ntfs-3g, needed for libfuse < v3 , useful to know if you face sluggish NTFS writes). This can be done in /etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf . Uncomment the [defaults] section label and modify ntfs_allow and ntfs_defaults to suit your needs. After that, you still need to restart the service:
systemctl restart udisks2
(maybe gracefully eject your removable volumes before this operation)

...and then I realized that it was really my shingled HDD that was slow, in that external USB enclosure :-(